# Using 'id' when writing methods for stacks of primitive data types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am writing a simple calculator app.  I want to implement a stack to store the operators the user enters.  Originally, I wanted to use chars but ran into some issues when I tried to use the removelastobject and last object for my pop method and addobject for my push method.

Instead I have used id as the type.  Is this wrong or are there better ways of solving this issue?

In my .h:

```
//Brain.h
-(void)pushOperator:(id)op;
```

In my .m:

```
 //Brain.m
 #import Brain.h
 @interface CalculatorBrain()
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *operatorStack;//This is the one I'm asking about
 @end

 @implementation CalculatorBrain

 @synthesize operatorStack = _operatorStack;


 - (NSMutableArray *) operatorStack
 {
    if (! _operatorStack)
     {
         _operatorStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
     return _operatorStack;
 }

-(void)pushOperator:(id)op
{
    [self.operatorStack addObject:op];
}

-(id)popOperator
{
    NSObject *op = [self.operatorStack lastObject];
    if (op)
    {
        [self.operatorStack removeLastObject];
    }
    return op;
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, your operator isn't an object type, but rather a basic data type. You can pass an NSValue which can then be claimed as an id, but I'm pretty sure your 'operators' are not object types. Can you give some more information on what you will be passing to this class?

Comment: @RileyE The operators I want to pass will be the basic operations, ie + - / *

Comment: So, characters or bytes. Then you cannot use id, you will have to use the specific data type or void * and convert.

Comment: @RileyE Ok thanks, now I just need to figure out what type of array is best to store chars in.

Comment: A char array would be a good way to go: char myCharArray[] = {'+', '-', '/', '*'};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your operator isn't an object type, but rather a basic data type. You can pass an NSValue which can then be claimed as an id, but I'm pretty sure you'd be better suited with a specific primitive value.

If you setup your methods to receive char pointers, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using id would be okay, but I think you may want to use an abstract class and derive your operators from that. Then you can use

```
-(void)pushOperator:(MyOperator)op;
```

Answer (score 0):

NSArray only stores objects; you can't store primitive types in one.  If you just want to store values, you can wrap them in instances of NSNumber or NSValue.